# Kafka Spark Streaming: How to run Spark SQL query on multiple tables created by spark steaming?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka-streams

I'm streaming multiple Kafka topics and creating tables out of them. How to run spark SQL queries on these tables when there's new data entering the stream?

```
public class SparkApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Spark3App")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "topic_1")
                .load()
                .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
                .select(functions.get_json_object(functions.col("value"),"$.data").alias("data"))
                .withColumn("data", functions.from_json(functions.col("data"), Regions.data)).select("data.*");

        df.writeStream()
                .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
                .outputMode("update")
                .format("memory")
                .queryName("Regions")
                .start();

        Dataset<Row> df1 = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "topic_2")
                .load()
                .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
                .select(functions.get_json_object(functions.col("value"),"$.data").alias("data"))
                .withColumn("data", functions.from_json(functions.col("data"), Projects.data)).select("data.*");

        df1.writeStream()
                .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
                .outputMode("update")
                .format("memory")
                .queryName("Projects")
                .start();

        spark.sql("Select Projects.project_name, Regions.region_name from Projects "
                    + "Join Regions ON  Regions.region_name = Projects.region_name")
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

How to keep the application running continuously and have it listening to the streams and run the SQL query whenever there's data in the stream? The ultimate goal is to write the output of the SQL query to another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Need to join 2 streams first.

```
val joinedDF = df.join(
  df1,
  expr("""
  project_name = region_name
  """),
  joinType = "inner"  
)
```

Once done, execute sql query on every micro batch

```
val query = joinedDF.writeStream.option("checkpointLocation", checkPointLocation).foreachBatch { (microbacth, batchId) => {

  microbacth.createOrReplaceTempView("final_table")

  val result = spark.sql("Select project_name, region_name from final_table")

  result.limit(5).show()
  // Additional logic

}}.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")).outputMode("update").start()

query.awaitTermination()
```